# How to correctly configure Flow backend for LSP mode?

Tags: javascript, lsp-mode, lsp-ui

I'm using `spacemacs` @develop (branch). I can't use `lsp` and `lsp-ui`. In vscode everything works (using flow lsp mode). With `company-flow` I can also make it working.

When opening a `.js` file with `// @flow` comment the lsp mode is activating automatically and tries to run the flow server and crashes:

```
Server flow-ls:7818 status:starting exited with status exit. Do you want to restart it? (y or n) y
```

Each time I'm trying to restart I see the same thing. So the type inspection and type checks doesn't work. 
Syntax is highlighted but I think it doesn't work (when I set `js2-mode-show-parse-errors nil` variable in the layers variable I see different view (eg the `import type` is not highlighted in red).

I'm running the latest version of flow, and have `flow-bin` installed (same version) in the package (`node_modules`) and globally. `flow` binary is in the PATH.

Comment: If the LSP server crashes, the problem is a bug in the LSP server, not in Emacs.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check the corresponding stderr log
2. Make sure the language server runs in the terminal

Comment: I was making a test both with `flow` and `flow lsp` run in terminal. In each case Emacs tries spaw it's own flow process (it calls it `flow-ls`) without success - the message in the `*Messages*` buffer is: _flow-ls<1> has exited (exited abnormally with code 3)_

Comment: OK, I've sorted it out. Please see the other answer. We don't need to run the language server (`flow lsp`) ourselves. lsp-mode will do it for us.

Answer (score 0):

1. Install `flow-bin` (globally or as a dependency in your `package.json`).
2. Make sure that the LSP project root is the same as your JavaScript project and you have the `.flowconfig` file there. (that was my initial error)
3. Install `flow-js2-mode` package to your Emacs.
4. Enable `flow-js2-mode` in javascript files - this is to enable Flow syntax.

   ```
   (add-hook 'js2-mode-hook #'flow-js2-mode))
   ```
5. All JavaScript files in the flow mode must have `// @flow` comment at the beginning of the file.